# How would you tail a log via a bash script without the script ending?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple script that takes a users input for a `remote host address` and then based on the selection that they make for which log they want to tail, the script will start tailing that log.

Example:

```
printf "\nEnter the customers Cloud URL:\n"
read -r customerURL

printf "\nWhich log do you want to tail?\n1. JLOG\n2. CLOG\n3. HLOG\n"
read -r whichlog

ssh "$customerURL"
tail -f /path/to/log
```

When doing this, the script runs but then once it is done SSH'ing into the host, it ends. Is what I am trying to do possible? Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: The `ssh` command doesn't exit until you log *out* of the shell on the remote host, at which point the `tail` command will run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine the ssh and the tail so the tail runs on the remote host instead of the local one.

```
ssh "$customerURL" tail -f /path/to/log
```

Comment: Perfecto!   Looking at @Nick Bull's comment, it got me thinking. If we have scripts that are on the remote host that we can run, for example: apache_status will spit out stats on the apache web server on the host....is there a way to string that along with the ssh command so it runs?

Answer (score 2):

Use a background process:

```
tail -f /path/to/log &
```

If ending your SSH session kills commands, use `nohup`:

```
nohup tail -f /path/to/log &
```

You can also send this via `ssh`:

```
ssh ubuntu@192.101.0.1 nohup tail -f /path/to/log &
```